# Rails: Child Record not Tracking Changes in Parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, model-associations

I'm sure this is ordinary Rails behavior, and I'm missing something fundamental, but what is it?

A child belongs to a parent, a parent has many members.

```
parent = Parent.create(:name=>"Kerkhoff, J")
child = parent.children.create(:first_name => "Sally")
puts child.parent.name    # ==> Kerkhoff, J
parent.update_attributes(:name=>'Zorro, A')
puts parent.name           # ==> 'Zorro, A'
puts child.parent.name    # ==> 'Kerkhoff, J'
child.save       # ==> true  (Does saving the child refresh its parent.name?)
puts child.parent.name    # ==> 'Kerkhoff, J'    (No)
child = Child.find(child.id)      # reload child from database
puts child.parent.name    # ==> 'Zorro, A'  (This does refresh the name)
```

Although the `name` attribute of `parent` has been changed, and though `child` continues to refer to the same parent, it does not reflect the parent's updated attribute. It is not a matter of the `update_attributes` failing, either. If Sally's record (`child`) is retrieved again from the database, the `name` attribute reflects `parent`'s new value.

What is going on here?

Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a lack of an object map in ActiveRecord. Saving the child object without modifying the parent will not refresh the parent.

To refresh the association, do something like `child.parent(true).name`.

Comment: Inside scoop: Rails 3.1 will probably have an [object map](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/76).